# Sonata Admin override template form_admin_fields.html.twig

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I want to fully customize the way expanded choice looks in the admin edit form. I have found a template that shows it:

```
vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/Form/form_admin_fields.html.twig
```

I also have found a list of templates you can override in SonataAdmin
https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/templates.html
Unfortunately, there is not **form_admin_fields.html.twig** in the list. So I'm wondering how can override that template or at least **{% block choice_widget_expanded %}** from that template.

Comment: Just an idea: Build you own form type and use that in sonata admin, https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has to be overridden on the level of the storage bundle.

For instance, if using Doctrine and SonataAdminDoctrineOrmBundle, it can easily be overridden in configuration like so:

```
sonata_doctrine_orm_admin:
    templates:
        form: ["My/Templates/form_admin_fields.html.twig"]
```

Be sure to extend the doctrine form_admin_fields.html.twig in your own form_admin_fields.html.twig (rather than the base sonata admin twig file), ie:

```
{% extends '@SonataDoctrineORMAdmin/Form/form_admin_fields.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: Thank you, you rock!